# SystemC how to get interactive user input

Tags: c++, verilog, hdl, systemc

I would like to take commands interactively from a user from standard input in a SystemC simulation.  I am using Mentor Questa and it seems that nothing from cout is printed to prompt the user (even with a flush immediately after the stream to cout).  I am using "getline" from iostream to get input.  Does someone know how to accomplish this?  Or has anyone seen a complete example with explanations as to how one would accomplish this?

### Edit:

So, it looks like running vsim with the "-c" and "-keepstdout" options causes some really odd behavior.  Running vsim with "-keepstdout" causes the GUI to launch but stdin and stdout are sent to the launching terminal.  So perhaps this is a Questa bug and not a SystemC question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SystemC is C++. You can use standard C++ techniques for user I/O.

Comment: But I think Questa might override std::cout when compiling with sccom.  Either that or Questa vsim captures stdout.  For whatever the reason, I cannot get std::cout to output text to a user.  I think after further investigation, my problem is not in SystemC but in the simulator.